# TensorFlow InvalidArgumentError/Value error occurs with small change of code

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_data = np.linspace(0, 1000000, 1000)
y_true = np.sin(x_data)
y_true += np.random.randn(len(x_data))




feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10,10,10], optimizer=lambda:
                                  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
                                      learning_rate=0.1
                                  ))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_true,    test_size=0.3)

input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': X_train},y_train,
                                                batch_size=8,     num_epochs=None,
                                                shuffle=True)

train_input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': X_train},y_train,
                                                      batch_size=8, num_epochs=1000,
                                                      shuffle=False)
test_input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': X_test},y_test,
                                                     batch_size=8, num_epochs=1000,
                                                     shuffle=False)


estimator.train(input_fn=input_function, steps=1000)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_function, steps=1000)
test_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_function, steps=1000)


print('TRAINING DATA METRICS')
print(train_metrics)
print()

print('TEST DATA METRICS')
print(test_metrics)
print()
```

**Works very well.
But if I change line `y_true = np.sin(x_data)` into  `y_true=tf.square(x_data)`, I get an error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1576, in _create_c_op
>       c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [1000], [1,700], [1,700], [1].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/PycharmProjects/TF_API_2/api.py", line 21, in 
>       X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_true, test_size=0.3)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py", line 2059, in train_test_split
>       safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py", line 2059, in 
>       safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils__init__.py", line 162, in safe_indexing
>       return X[indices]
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 524, in _slice_helper
>       name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 690, in strided_slice
>       shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 10187, in strided_slice
>       name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1731, in **init**
>       control_input_ops)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1579, in _create_c_op
>       raise ValueError(str(e))
>   ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [1000], [1,700], [1,700], [1].

**If I use **2 instead of tf.square, the code cannot compiled too, with error:
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
Traceback (most recent call last):**

> File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/PycharmProjects/TF_API_2/api.py", line 35, in 
>       estimator.train(input_fn=input_function, steps=1000)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 376, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1145, in _train_model
>       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1173, in _train_model_default
>       saving_listeners)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1451, in _train_with_estimator_spec
>       _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 583, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1059, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1150, in run
>       raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1135, in run
>       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1215, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata))
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 635, in after_run
>       raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
>   tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.

**What is the problem with this one line [`y_true = tf.square(x_data)`]?**

Comment: Don't mix numpy and tensorflow operations. I'd suggest `y_true=np.square(x_data)` instead.

Comment: OK. But still get same "tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training." error.

Comment: Looks like you ran into numeric overflow. Your numbers are just too big. If you are trying to teach the network how to square numbers, you may want to try it on smaller numbers.

Comment: Oh. Right. I changed x_data to x_data=np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000) and the problem does not occur. Please add your last comment as answer, so I will be able to mark this as solution.

Comment: @coldspeed Please tell me, why program outputs that big loss: TRAINING DATA METRICS
{'average_loss': 13975338000.0, 'label/mean': 349618.28, 'loss': 111802700000.0, 'prediction/mean': 359011.06, 'global_step': 1000}

TEST DATA METRICS
{'average_loss': 12280204000.0, 'label/mean': 293979.97, 'loss': 98241634000.0, 'prediction/mean': 325393.22, 'global_step': 1000}

Comment: I did not run your code, so I'm not sure. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: OK. No problem :)

Comment: So, I think it is just the way DNNRegressor computes the loss (sum of losses for all examples), and I think because the values are large, you see large loss values. How is the accuracy? It should still be decent.

Comment: I predicted some values, and program for ALL x_values predict same y, like 0.9783435

Comment: @coldspeed New lines: 
new_data = np.linspace(0, 1000, 10)
input_function_predict = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x':new_data}, shuffle=False)
print(list(estimator.predict(input_fn=input_function_predict))) 
gave the output:
 [{'predictions': array([0.9783435], dtype=float32)}, {'predictions': array([0.9783435], dtype=float32)}, {'predictions': array([0.9783435], dtype=float32)}, ...

Comment: Start simple and try this for numbers 1-10?

Comment: Same problem still

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue could be. Maybe open a new question, someone else will figure it out?

Comment: @coldspeed OK. I will. Still, great thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct issues here:

#1, don't mix numpy and tensorflow operations together. Unless you're evaluating your graph in eager execution mode, they almost always never go together.

#2, when your network produces NaNs after a few iterations, that's usually a good sign you're running into numeric overflow/underflow. In this case, the culprit is `x_data` which has input too large. Either normalize it (0-1) or reduce the range of the generated data (how about `np.random.randint`?).